# Connection between parity/time transformations, conformal-style dilation, and spin statistics

Tags: special-relativity, parity, time-reversal-symmetry

The operator $\left(2 \pi i t + \Delta\right)x^\mu \partial_\mu$ generates, for half-integer $t$, a combined parity and time-reversal and a dilation:

$$
\mathrm{e}^{\left(2 \pi i t + \Delta\right)x^\mu \partial_\mu}f(x^\nu) = f\left(\left(-1\right)^{2t}\mathrm{e}^\Delta x^\nu\right).
$$
Is there a good reference that describes this operator and how these ideas (parity/time reversal and dilation) combine in special relativity or its (maybe conformal) extensions?

There also seems to be a connection to the spin-statistics theorem if $f$ is a function of distance between two identical particles of spin $t$ (but why only if a function of distance between two identical particles and not for a function of a single particle's position?), and I seem to have lost the C part of CPT symmetry as there is no obvious connection to charge: a reference or breakdown of this operator would be appreciated.